# Migration of EJB 2.1 from Weblogic to JBoss EAP 7.2

Tags: java, jboss7.x, weblogic-10.x, ejb-2.x

I have been trying to migrate EJB 2 which runs on top of the WebLogic server  which should run on JBoss 7.2 server. My application was developed using XDoclet tools. I came to know that the tool is no longer in use.

In my old `build.xml`, there were many `ejbdoclet` elements being used to generate value objects and WebLogic-specific deployment descriptors. How do I change or re-write the `build.xml` without using these `ejbgen` and `ejbdoclets` for EJB 2.1?

Please provide what the xml files are needed/required to convert/deploy and accessing the EJB 2.1 application in JBoss EAP 7.2.

If you provide the sample example application (EJB 2.1 in JBoss 7), that would be a great help!

Your response in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider leaving EJB standard behind.  If you were using Spring Boot you'd have POJOs that would run in an executable JAR or a WAR file if you had to deploy to JBOSS.  It's a better way to go.